# Customize AssertionError in Python

Tags: python, assert

I'm trying to add some text for all assertion errors in my code.

This is my code:

```
class AssertionError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        Exception.__init__(self, msg)
        self.message = msg + "+ SOME TEXT"

assert 1 == 2, "FAIL"
```

Result is

```
__main__.AssertionError: FAIL
```

I expected to see result: "FAIL + SOME TEXT"

---

Problem is with unittest also.
I want add some text for all failed tests (Without updating all text message).

```
import unittest

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        self.assertTrue(False, "FAIL!")

    def test2(self):
        self.assertLessEqual(10, 2, "FAIL!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work with unittest.

If I fail in test I don't see additional info.

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to [Morgan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33439080/1) but uses a slightly different way to accomplish the same result:

```
>>> class AssertionError(AssertionError):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        super().__init__(msg + ' SOME TEXT')

>>> assert 1 == 2, 'FAIL'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    assert 1 == 2, 'FAIL'
AssertionError: FAIL SOME TEXT
```

Comment: Is there any real difference between subclassing `Exception` and `AssertionError`? I'm actually not sure. I would assume not, because you're shadowing the builtin `AssertionError`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The new `AssertionError` will shadow the version in the `builtins` module while in the current namespace only. If another module is using `buitins`' `AssertionError` and since `AssertionError` inherits from the original class, another module could potentially still catch the error if it occurs.

Comment: Huh, interesting. I would've assumed that it would still throw something that another module recognized as `AssertionError`, but that's good to know.

Comment: It doasn't work during fail unittest.assertTrue(False, "FAIL")

Comment: @Helga You may need to `import unittest.case` and then `unittest.case.TestCase.failureException = AssertionError` to get it to work as expected. Alternatively, you could write `from unittest.case import TestCase as TC` and `TC.failureException = AssertionError` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're not doing anything with `self.message = msg + "+ SOME TEXT"`. You have to pass the custom message you want to `Exception.__init__`.

This will work for you:

```
class AssertionError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.message = msg + " SOME TEXT"
        super().__init__(self, self.message)
assert 1 == 2, "FAIL"
```

If you want to view the message in the future, you can use a try/except and catch the custom message like this:

```
try:
    assert 1 == 2, "FAIL"
except AssertionError as e:
    print(e.message)
```

Answer (score 1):

This variant keeps the exception exactly as it was raised and modifies its string representation only:

```
class AssertionError(AssertionError):
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + "SOME TEXT"
```

(credit: subclassing taken from Noctis' answer)